# How can I reroute in BeforeEnterObserver in the view before AppLayout is rendered in Vaadin 14 (Vaadin Flow)

Tags: vaadin, vaadin-flow, vaadin14

So for example let's I have:

```
public class MainView extends AppLayout {
   public MainView() {
      User user = VaadinSession.getAttribute("user");
      if(user.isCheckSomething())
          Span span = new Span("Hello " + user.getFirstname());
   }
}
```

This will fail with a NPE if the user is not already logged in as getting the User from the session will be null. Now I could add a null check before the `if(user.isCheckSomething())` but ideally I would prefer not to have the `AppLayout` rendered at all if the user is not logged in. That is I'd rather fail in the view through `BeforeEnterObserver` in the `public void beforeEnter(BeforeEnterEvent event)` method however the `AppLayout` is called and created before the `beforeEnter(...)` method is called.

In other words how can I force the instantiation of `AppLayout` to be skipped entirely if the user isn't logged in through the view so that the `AppLayout` is never constructed.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As a rule of thumb, it's really not reliable to work with the UI in the constructor in any way, since it's not initialized yet.

AppLayout has its own `afterNavigation` method which should be called after BeforeEnterEvent.

```java
public class MainView extends AppLayout {
    @Override
    protected void afterNavigation() {
        super.afterNavigation();
        User user = VaadinSession.getAttribute("user");
        if(user.isCheckSomething())
            Span span = new Span("Hello " + user.getFirstname());
    }
```

So in beforeEnter method you will reroute to login, otherwise the after navigation from the parent layout will be fired.

```java
@Override
public void beforeEnter(BeforeEnterEvent event) {
    if (!isAuthenticated()) {
        event.rerouteTo(LoginView.class);
    }
}
```

You can either implement `BeforeEnterObserver` in each of your views and check if user is authenticated over and over again... or you can do it once:

```java
@SpringComponent
public class AuthenticationControl implements VaadinServiceInitListener {
     @Override
    public void serviceInit(ServiceInitEvent event) {
        event.getSource().addUIInitListener(uiEvent -> {
            final UI ui = uiEvent.getUI();
            ui.addBeforeEnterListener(/* do the check here, either with a method reference or create a separate listener class */);
        });
     }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, that actually helped a lot. I didn't realize the interface was respected on the AppLayout. And thanks for the tip for the authentication. I was heading in that direction as part of converting a Vaadin 8 webapp but wasn't quite there yet.

Comment: @StephaneGrenier interestingly, AppLayout defines it's own `afterNavigation()` method, which is not exactly the same as AfterNavigationObserver's `afterNavigation(AfterNavigationEvent)`. But I think you could also use the interface on AppLayout subclass, since it should apply to *any* Component.